# Would it influence physics if there were no observers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, observers

In any physics like quantum physics or relativity?

Comment: "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?"      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest

Comment: 1. The concept of "observer" in a technical sense is an inherent part of relativity. You cannot remove this concept without "changing physics" by definition. 2. It is unclear whether you mean observer in this technical sense or in the colloquial sense of just someone who looks at something. In any case, this seems to be a vague, open-eneded hypothetical question of a "What if?"-type, which is explicitly [declared off-topic in the help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

"Physics" as a science is something that humanity has made up. So, **if there were no humans to observe the universe, there would be no physics**. In other words, yes, physics would be affected if there were no observers. However, if we're talking about **the *laws* of physics** - the facts we humans have proven about the way the universe works - these ***would* remain unchanged**. These laws are not affected by observation; e.g. the electrostatic force would continue to act on charged particles even if nobody were around to see it doing so.

Your question does seem related to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle from quantum mechanics. This principle states that we can only observe certain facts about particles at very small scales. For example, if we know the momentum of an electron with perfect certainty, then we can not know its position with 100% certainty. When Heisenberg came up with his theory, he believed this uncertainty was due to how we actually observe particles. It was later realized that the uncertainty of quantum measurements is actually intrinsic to the system, so the act of observing doesn't actually make a change in what's going on. It only changes what we scientists know. No effect here.

**There is, in physics, something called the "observer effect".** This applies to some systems which are actually changed by the act of taking a measurement on them. When you take the pressure of a car tire, for example, some air will escape and change the pressure of the tire. The system has been affected by the act of taking a measurement. Quantum physicists have noted that some measurements can be affected even by indirect observation (like if we could measure the tire pressure by measuring the speed of the car, and measuring the speed somehow changed the tire's pressure). Some physicists hypothesize that this is evidence that the conscious mind can actually affect the physical world. Although this is unproven, it could be an answer to your question.

Similarly, you can think about how humans have influenced our understanding of physics the science. Calling protons positively charged and electrons negatively charged is an arbitrary choice made by humans. If it were some other intelligent race observing the universe, it's quite possible that what they defined as "physics" would be very different from what we define like that. That's getting off-topic, though.

**To sum up, whether "physics" would change if there were no observers depends on how you define "physics".** The laws of physics are by definition immutable, but individual occurrences that we study with physics and our own understanding of the term "physics" would definitely be different if nobody were around.